# Different color to same series line in highstock graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have a highstock graph as shown in the picture below with a plotband with the color red. Is there a way to color the series that is marked with a rectangle, that is the circle inside the red plot band to be set to a different color ?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The feature You requested will be available only after the release of Highcharts v 3.0. You can check other details **[`here`](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/787281-threshold-option-for-colors)** . [**`Beta`**](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/53-highcharts-3-0-beta-released) version of the required version is released although.

Threshold option for colors [**`demo`**](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/PMyHQ/).